# Get All input data of radio type using javascript in html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have html page which contains radio type fields. I want to retrieve only specific data which belongs to the radio button fields.
I used `document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]')` ,but it returns only the data of first radio button field. But I want data of all radio button fields.
Please anyone help me out.!!

Comment: You should use `document.querySelectorAll` to select all radio buttons and use `forEach` to access each element value. Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#example